# Why does it take 4-5 hours to charge a small hearing aid? Can a larger NFC coil shorten charging time?

Tags: lithium-ion, charging

Oticon makes hearing aids with wireless charging. For one of their models they use a size 13 Lithium-ion battery which corresponds to 270-320mAh. They claim that it takes 4-5 hours to charge this battery using an NFC coil.

A quick Google search on Lithium-ion charging time yields:

> It takes approximately 150 minutes to charge a new li-ion battery to 100% 1,400mAh.

I'm not sure about the validity of this [source](https://m.greenway-battery.com/news/Charging-lithium-batteries-for-the-first-time-58.html) but the difference in charging time is large.
Why does it take so long to charge a small hearing aid?

Question:  Are there things that I could do to achieve faster charging rates. Would it be possible for me to design a faster charger?

- Would a larger NFC coil yield a faster charging time for the battery inside the hearing aid?
- Is there any other way to speed up the charging time.
- Would contact charging be the best way to go?

Comment: Most people sleep for 5hrs or more per day. Why reinvent the wheel when this time is perfectly applicable for recharging?  The size limits the charging current; to go faster would require a bigger hearing-aid.  Sure, it *could* be done, but at a *cost*.

Comment: @rdtsc if people forget to charge it or if the aid is not properly connected to the charging device they are practically deaf for 5 hours.

Comment: "Would contact charging be the best way to go?" Wireless charging is always less efficient than wired charging.  It will likely take longer.  However, my larger concerns are the environmental impacts of wireless charging.  Being less efficient means that they are also often larger contributors to CO2 emission from increased power consumption.  Cell phones as well...

Comment: @rdtsc But why would charging go faster with larger hearing aid? Is it because a larger coil can provide larger current? I'm really looking for some equations that can put things into perspective.

Comment: Kuba's answer is good. It's a design decision for a range of reasons which can be guessed at but which are not knowable. Cost and battery longevity are both helped. If the charger proper is inside the aid then direct connection will not help. If the battery is remocable then faster charging is PROBABLY possible but this depends on battery. The majority of charging will occur in under half the time taken for a full charge (usually) so usefully shorter charging may not lose much capacity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a design decision. In the product specification phase, they literally put down on “paper” a full charge time. It’s arbitrary, but you have to choose a number, and shorter isn’t always better for various reasons. Faster charging

- puts more stress on the power path,
- produces more heat in a product intended to be very small, with very
  limited heat dissipation capability,
- decreases battery life due to higher charge temperature and faster rate of reactions that degrade the cell,
- increases the weight and size of a product intended to be miniature,
- adds BOM pressures that may limit part availability,
- etc.

In other words: someone decided it to be so not because they couldn’t make charging faster, but because it likely wouldn’t make a better product overall.

We have to remember that a lot of product specifications are not limited because the engineers couldn’t reach a better number. Engineers are usually thrilled if given a chance to “improve the numbers”. I’m almost sure the team putting the product together could have made a hearing aid just a bit larger and heavier but with vastly better “numbers”. Engineers like the “no holds barred, we have to get to the Moon” projects. Except the product would be unaffordable, the company would go out of business, and they’d have to go job hunting. Engineers would rather engineer than job hunt. Ergo, they stick to the trade off and keep the job :)

Comment: I think for hearing-aids in particular, extra emphasis is placed on small size and mass.  Nobody is going to wear big, heavy hearing aids, even if they *did* recharge in an hour.

Comment: Please upvote the question. I asume that if its worth answering its worth upvoting :-)

Comment: A useful answer. Notes that various possibly inobvious design decisions can matter more than optimising one parameter.